# AVR Rapid Fire Mod... I hit a wall and need some help

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, avr, pcb-design, breadboard

Title says it; I'm making a rapid fire mod chip with the 328p family of chips right now (I'm going to scale down to whatever the smallest chip is that will safely hold the final software). I'm a fan of BASIC so I'm using Bascom and a USBASP programmer.

I've hooked up the chip with a 20Mhz clock and 22pF caps, as well as a power\status LED, and an LCD for visual debugging (because it really does make a huge difference). So it's a very basic setup.

Here's the problem: when I'm on the BB with a regular tactile switch, I can get the program to work totally fine. However, when I run wires from the contact points on the controller and hook them up to the corresponding points on the AVR, the program acts as if there's no button present, or rather it almost is looking like it's acting as if I'm just holding the button down, and I'm not. I've tried high side, low side, every possible side, and it isn't working as it should.

Most people use the PIC controllers, and they just run the controller contact points direct (or through 330R) without a problem. I've installed plenty of these for other people, and it's not complicated. So in theory I should be able to do the same, so why is it tripping out?

Here's my Bascom code:

```
   'Name: Azula Outlaw Mod MCU Firmware
   'Version: a1
   'Designed by: Dominic M, Luciano
   'Development MCU: ATMega328P
   'Oscillator: 20 MHz Crystal
   'Copyright: (c) 2014-2015 Dominic M. Luciano, Luciano Incorporated, and Azula Microtech
   'All Rights Reserved.

   $regfile = "m328pdef.dat"
   $crystal = 2000000

   'PIN\IO INITS
   '---------------------------------------
   'OUT
   'Init LCD Backlight  (For Visual Debugging)
   LCDLIGHT Alias PortB.0
   Config LCDLIGHT = Output

   'Init PWR LED
   PWRLED Alias PORTB.1
   Config PWRLED = Output

   'IN
   'Init Function Switch, Start Pull Up
   F_SW Alias PinD.2
   PortD.2 = 1
   Config F_SW = Input

   'LCD INIT
   '---------------------------------------
   'Config the LCD for visual debugging
   Config lcd = 16 * 2
   Config lcdpin = PIN , DB4 = PORTD.4 , DB5 = PORTD.5 , DB6 = PORTD.6 , DB7 = PORTD.7 , E = PORTD.1 , RS = PORTD.0
   Config lcdmode = PORT

   'VARIABLE AND SUB CALLS
   '---------------------------------------
   Declare Sub FClick()
   Dim FCount as Byte
   Dim FState as Byte                                          'State flag

   'INTERRUPTS AND SLEEP\STANDBY
   '---------------------------------------

   'STARTUP SEQUENCE
   '---------------------------------------
   LCDLIGHT = 1                                                'Start LCD Backlight
   PWRLED = 1

   'MAIN LOOP
   '---------------------------------------
   Main:

   Cls
   LCD "No Activity"

   'Stabilize
   Waitms 250

   Do

   If F_SW = 1 Then

   If FState = 0 then
   Gosub FClick
   ElseIf FState = 1 Then
   Waitms 500
   FState = 0
   End If

   End If

   Loop

   'Subroutine for the function button
   '(The button that tells the AVR to take commands)
   Sub FClick()

   Cls
   LCD "Input Settings"

   '~2 second wait until reset and goto Main

   Dim Flash as Byte

   Do
   PWRLED = 0
   Waitms 500
   PWRLED = 1
   Waitms 500
   Incr Flash
   Loop Until Flash = 2

   'Change State Flag
   Incr FState

   'Set Vars
   Flash = 0
   FCount = 0

   'Exit Sub and Return to Main Loop
   Goto Main

   End Sub
```

Sorry about any mess in my code. It's still really rough. I was trying to get one subroutine down because the rest of it is all the same subs basically.

Here's a shot of my workspace. Once again, sorry for the mess:
[image: Breadboard and 360controller inside]

So if you can offer any help, I'd appreciate it. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Not familiar with BASCOM but have done plenty of C coding on Mega328s. I don't see anything that turns on the internal pullup resistor. PB.2 appears to be set as an input, but nothing indicates a pullup. Usually that would involve DDRB but that could be hidden in BASCOM code. Try just adding a 3.3K pullup from the input to Vcc, and connect the switch between the input and ground.

Jim Wagner
Oregon Research Electronics

Comment: This line is supposedly supposed to turn on the internal pullups:

PortD.2 = 1

But I'm going to try that resistor externally too. I'm honestly so baffled as to why it doesn't work as is since everyone elses chips work. But I'll give this a shot

Thank you. By the way, I live in Oregon as well; Southern Oregon area.

Comment: Well I took your advice but still no luck. I have determined that it is in fact acting as if there is NO INPUT. I tried another 328P, and a 324P, another controller, tried reading it off the ADC (which just showed 1023 no matter what), and I'm seriously stumped. It should be reading the voltage changes from the controller contact points. And that should change the pin's state with no extra parts; just a direct line. If I can't get a solution, I might as well scrap it because that is literally the whole project. So I'm praying for a solution cause I'd love to finish it.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, it almost looks like you've got the down and left button connections connected to ground on the gamepad, rather than the signal side of the buttons. From what I can see in that image, you will need 4 wires going to the signal side of the buttons (the side not connected to the ground fill), and one other wire connecting the ground on the gamepad to the ground on your AVR.

Second, I suspect your issue is either a wiring or pull up problem, which is easy enough to diagnose by measuring the voltage between ground and your input pins on the AVR. When the button is not pressed, it should read 5V, and drop to 0V when pressed. If the voltage is waving somewhere between, there is likely no resistor pulling that side up to 5V (either externally or by enabling the internal pull ups) - and a floating input like that will just play havok with the AVR behavior.

Comment: I was in the process of testing different sides of the D-Pad contacts to see if that fixed anything. But it didn't. Everyone elses' mod chips use one wire attached to the + side of the buttons. But I just realized I'm using two different power sources with no ground from the controller going anywhere. However, I had them all wired to the USBASP power only first, and it still wasn't working right. Peculiar.

Comment: Wiring is sound on the MCU itself, and running wires to contact points is pretty cut and dry. The voltage isn't wavering. So I'm going to assume it's because I didn't connect the ground. I'll to run it all on the same supply again tomorrow and see if that fixes it. Thanks

Comment: So keeping everything on the same VCC\GND didn't work. I tested every single voltage point on the game pad too, and soldered the wires on the game pad button contacts to all of the high points, not GND points. Each button reads at ~2V when pressed. However the AVR still won't recognize this. It's as if nothing is on the port of the AVR. Incredibly baffling and frustrating. I'm seriously at a loss with this one. I've tried everything, including different controllers, AVR's.... I really don't want to have to scrap this one. Is it an AVR thing? Is the PIC the only MCU that this can work on? Help?

Comment: It should read 0V (or extremely close to 0V) when pressed, not somewhere between 0V and 5V. When you say ~2V, where are your multimeter probes (what are you measuring between)?

Comment: I think you may be misunderstanding the entire concept. This doesn't use buttons in the sense that you are thinking. All the button contacts are on the gamepad. The AVR's job us to read the high\low state, and then the AVR will change the state of the gamepad buttons utomatically based off what the programming says to do. So the AVR is just reading the state of the gamepad buttons; it's a single wire from the gamepad button contact to the AVR pin. But the AVR is acting like the pin has nothing connected to it.

The ~2V is the voltage across the button contacts on the gamepad.

Comment: Okay, so as far as I can tell, you're trying to read when a gamepad button is pressed, and then when it is released, "override" that button, controlling the signal to the gamepad electronics to pretend that the button is being pressed. Normally (though possibly not on the XBox), a button has one side grounded, and the other pulled up to VCC (is the gamepad supply voltage 5V?) through a resistance. When the button is unpressed, the voltage across the button is equal to VCC, when it is pressed, the signal side of the button gets shorted to ground, and the voltage should be 0V.

Comment: More or less, yes. One side is in fact VCC and the other GND, except the 360 gamepad voltage is 3.3V, not 5V, and from what I see, the button voltage may be ~2 to ~2.2V (my equipment doesn't read in decimals). There are plenty of mod chips on the market for the XB360 controller, so it is in fact possible. So I'm lost as to why I can't get it to work. It seems incredibly simple.

Comment: And so, coming back to my previous comment, if the button is working, the signal side of it should drop to 0V when pressed - which isn't the value you've measured (according to your previous comment).

Comment: It obviously doesn't work like that. When you complete the circuit with the conductive pads corresponding to each button, no "button" registers a voltage change anywhere. I'm putting "button" in quotes because they really aren't buttons in the typical sense like tactile or momentary switches, and that's important to understand. Even so, the AVR should be able to detect the voltage off of the gamepad "button" VCC side, yet it doesn't even when the multimeter shows ~2V going into the AVR pin.

Comment: And it's not the AVR because I'm tried a few 328P and 324P chips to no avail. Even the ADC reads 1023, and will not change value on either side of the gamepad "button" contacts

Comment: Hmm, okay. I was wondering if I was misunderstanding your problem, and so got out an old 360 controller and had a look. I'm measuring between the two sides of the top D-pad button, shown [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_tEXDJs4pCqbV9zMkFET2hKT2c/view?usp=sharing) . When unpressed, there is a voltage of around 3.3V. When [pressed](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_tEXDJs4pCqVlY3WVNzT0k4N00/view?usp=sharing), there is a voltage of between 0V and 1V, getting lower as I pressed harder. Does this look like the same situation you have?

Comment: Well there's different versions of the 360 controller, CG\CG2, and the older Matrix (you can tell what is what by a capacitor under the battery, or by the angle and quantity of the onboard MCU(s)). I'm using a CG2 controller which I believe had lower voltages than the Matrix controllers; unpressed it's reading ~2V, and pressed it does get lower as you said. So yes, it's basically the same situation. But now you understand that there is in fact some voltage for the AVR to read. So the question is why is the AVR not reading it?

Comment: Alright, gotcha. And that voltage is the same when measured at the input pin to your AVR, correct? The code listed above is checking for `If F_SW = 1 Then`, though a button press should return a low (F_SW=0), so it is checking for a high level. This leads on to a potential issue - your 2V input. The 328P only guarantees a pin to be read as high when the voltage is above 0.6 of the supply voltage. If your supply is 5V (is it?) this corresponds to a voltage of 3V as your minimum high level, which the input pin will never reach. Powering the 328P with 3.3V instead might solve this issue.

Comment: F_SW is a remnant from a tactile I had on there that I was using as a surrogate to just get my subs down. However I did in fact try both 0 and 1.... The supply is 5V from my USBasp, and the supply for the gamepad is like ~3V, so even if it's putting out 2V from the contacts, that's nowhere near, what, 5.6V? So then that's the problem right there. However, even if both were on a 3.3V supply, the buttons still don't seem to be putting out enough juice to get read as high. Is that just an AVR thing? Because if so that makes sense why people use PICs for this.

Comment: I also have many other chips on hand. I have the whole 48A\88A\328P line, as well as 324P chips. Do these all have that same "0.6" requirement?

Comment: When I say the threshold is "0.6 of the supply voltage", I mean VCC*0.6, which equals 3V for a 5V supply, and 1.98V for a 3.3V supply.

Comment: That makes WAY more sense now. Which page of the datasheet is that on for reference? Also, changing the voltage; on the front page of the DS, it shows voltages and frequencies. I've been running the program on the 8mhz RC (perfectly I might add), and I was going to use a 20mhz xtal in the end since the final program isn't going to be as simple, so am I going to be better off getting a 10mhz xtal now since it shows that 3.3V can max out only at 10mhz? Or will it just run my 20mhz xtal at 10mhz now?

Comment: Section 29.2 on page 303. As far as the crystal frequency, you're right in thinking the 20 MHz won't work at 3.3V properly. TBH the 8MHz internal oscillator is probably easily fast enough for your needs, and a more accurate crystal is often only necessary when you have some very tight timing requirements such as a precise baud rate for serial comms. If you want to use a crystal you'll need to find something around 10MHz or below, 8MHz being one of the most common. The info on max clock speeds is in section 19.3 on page 310.

Comment: You're the bomb, thank you. I've had no trouble with the internal RC osc, so I think I should be fine with it. I mean, the whole program is just running subroutines. I'm not doing any communications or anything. So I'd say 8mhz is completely acceptable; MCU's evidently don't work like PC's where fast clocks = better. Anyways, I'll give your suggestions a shot. I have to redo my breadboards because I needed them to unbrick an AVR. I'll let you know if I need more help. Thank you so much for sharing your knowledge and helping me out!

Comment: PS: One quick last question: If I were to get something like this (http://www.adafruit.com/products/735), would that solve my problem without the need to lower my AVR voltage level?

Comment: You could, but it's adding extra unneeded complexity. If it's inconvenient to try and use another, lower voltage power supply, you could simply use a [3.3V LDO regulator](http://www.adafruit.com/products/2166) to drop down from the 5V. I probably should have mentioned before, other  solutions include using the ADC on the 328P to literally measure the voltage, and determine the threshold yourself, or put another pullup resistor(as well as the one in the gamepad) on the input pin to pull the unpressed voltage above 3V.

Comment: I was having trouble reading with the ADC before. It just kept showing 1023 no matter what. And I do in fact know how to get the ADC running because I've used it for many other projects. So I just gave up on that angle. I actually was about to buy those exact LDO deals. They seemed perfect for dropping the voltage. I just had the epiphany that something like a buffer or op amp in line could like up-translate the signal so I don't need to tweak the AVR so much. In hindsight, it would leave an larger-than-needed PCB in the end, so LDO it is. Thanks again